# Print array list values with loop to div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array called desc that contains some text for each of it's values and change's length and values depending on what the user clicks on.

array:

```
desc[0] =  "manhole cover on foothpath on barrog gaa grounds kilbarrack road loose."
desc[1] =  "Footpath at driveway to 17 Maywood Lawn in bad state of disrepair."
```

I would like to display these array values in a div called #container. At the moment it just prints the last value of the array in #container rather that printing each of the the values in the list.

JavaScript:

```
 function incidentList(){
            for(var i=0; i<desc.length; ++i){
             $("#container").text(desc[i]);
        }
      }
```

Html:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 50%; height:97%; float:right;"></div>
```

How should I go about printing the full list with each array value underneath the last using a loop?

Comment: `function incidentList() { $("#container").text(desc.join("<br />")); }`

Comment: @Givi this would output '<br />' as text on the contatiner. You'll need to use `$.fn.html` instead.

Comment: @kayen Yes, you're right! ;)

Comment: @kayen should $.fn.html be used in place of "<br />"?

Comment: @wtmcm When you do `$(container).html('<br />')` it outputs the '<br />' as HTML content on the container i.e. as a line break, but when you do `$(container).text('<br />')` it simply displays it as plain text on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function incidentList(){
  var full_list = ""
  for(var i=0; i<desc.length; ++i){
      full_list = full_list + desc[i] + '<br>'
  }
  $("#container").text(full_list);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
$('#container').text(desc.join('\r\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function incidentList(){
   for(var i=0; i<desc.length; ++i){
       $("#container").text( $("#container").text() + desc[i] + '<br/>');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery .append method rather than .text

Answer (score 0):

```
 function incidentList(){
        for(var i=0; i<desc.length; ++i){
         $("#container").append(desc[i] +"<br/>");
    }
  }
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function incidentList(){
            for(var i=0; i<desc.length; ++i){
             $("#container").append(desc[i]);
        }
      }
```

the method `.text()` will replace the content of the div but `.append()` will append so you will have all the data displayed.